# Weird error in Eclipse with Android

Tags: android, eclipse

This didn't start happening until today but I am wondering what is causing it. Whenever I compile, like one out of every 10 times all of the sudden the same 2 errors show up, pointing to

```
this.onBackPressed();
```

and

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"
```

both of which give errors along the lines of 'requires API level of 5' or 'requires API level of 16.'

The thing is, the errors go away by clicking Project>>Clean each time, so because it runs fine I do that every time, but it just keeps happening. What could be causing this?

Comment: Make sure you do a refresh on the sources. I've had it happen where I've changed my underlying files (such as with a git command outside of Eclipse) and forget to refresh.

Answer (score 1):

These are [Lint](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/improving-w-lint.html) errors, which warn you if you are using API level features that are higher than your `minSdkVersion` (set in your `AndroidManifest.xml`).

For example, [onBackPressed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29) was introduced in API level 5. Attempting to call it on an API level 4 or lower device will cause the application to crash.

Of course, your application will work just fine if you run it on a device API level 5 or higher, hence why it appears to always work.

Answer (score 0):

If the minimum API level (that you set at the beginning of your project) is **lower than 5** (the error you are getting), Eclipse will give you an error because any device running **API 4 or lower** isn't supported for `this.onBackPressed();`, and devices running **API 15 or lower** isn't supported for the Holo Theme.

To **avoid these errors** you can either **change the API level of your project to 16**, or you could **remove** `android:theme ...`. Then you could **change the API level** of your project to **5** because nowadays most devices are Android 2.2, which is API 8.